# Delayed message in RabbitMQ

Tags: rabbitmq

Is it possible to send message via RabbitMQ with some delay?
For example I want to expire client session after 30 minutes, and I send a message which will be processed after 30 minutes.

Comment: Do you need to use RabbitMQ?

Comment: Yes, this feature available since RabbitMQ-3.5.8.   https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/

Comment: If you use Spring AMQP, there's [support for the plugin](https://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/reference/htmlsingle/#delayed-message-exchange).

Answer (score 32):

There are two approaches you can try:

**Old Approach:** Set the TTL(time to live) header in each message/queue(policy) and then introduce a DLQ to handle it. once the ttl expired your messages will move from DLQ to main queue so that your listener can process it.

**Latest Approach:** Recently RabbitMQ came up with **RabbitMQ Delayed Message Plugin** , using which you can achieve the same and this plugin support available since RabbitMQ-3.5.8.

You can declare an exchange with the type x-delayed-message and then publish messages with the custom header x-delay expressing in milliseconds a delay time for the message. The message will be delivered to the respective queues after **x-delay** milliseconds

```java
byte[] messageBodyBytes = "delayed payload".getBytes("UTF-8");
Map<String, Object> headers = new HashMap<String, Object>();
headers.put("x-delay", 5000);
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder props = new 
AMQP.BasicProperties.Builder().headers(headers);
channel.basicPublish("my-exchange", "", props.build(), messageBodyBytes);
```

More here: [git](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/)

Comment: The Delayed Message Plugin has a limitation on total delayed message count in queue since it it using Mnesia to store those delayed messages (https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange/issues/72)

Comment: The "delayed exchange plugin" is the most elegant solution but you have to be careful before to adopt it in a production-grade project. For the limitations mentioned by @henrylei it's possible to loose messages, since messages are stored without redundancy before to be actually published in the exchange. For heavy loads and critical features, the "fake" dead letter is still the most accountable alternative

Answer (score 14):

With the release of RabbitMQ v2.8, scheduled delivery is now available but as an indirect feature: http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/rabbitmq-scheduled-message-delivery.html

Comment: I tried this approach but hit a few issues, suggestions any one? http://blog.james-carr.org/2012/03/30/rabbitmq-sending-a-message-to-be-consumed-later/#comment-502703

Comment: I did a spike and hit a few showstoppers:

1. Messages are only DLQ:en when at the top of the Q (http://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html – Caveats section)
This means that if I first set msg 1 to expire in 4 hours and msg2 to expire in 1 hours msg2 will only expire after msg1 has expired.

2. The TTL for the message is kept by Rabbit so lets say you use a short timeout of 10 s. If the consumer hasn’t been able to consume the message withing 10 seconds after it expired (due to a backlog) it will be discarded and lost

The above has been verified with Rabbit 3.0.1

Do you guys see any workarounds?

Answer (score 12):

Thanks to [Norman's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21334661), I could implement it in Node.js.

Everything is pretty clear from the code.

```js
var ch = channel;
ch.assertExchange("my_intermediate_exchange", 'fanout', {durable: false});
ch.assertExchange("my_final_delayed_exchange", 'fanout', {durable: false});

// setup intermediate queue which will never be listened.
// all messages are TTLed so when they are "dead", they come to another exchange
ch.assertQueue("my_intermediate_queue", {
      deadLetterExchange: "my_final_delayed_exchange",
      messageTtl: 5000, // 5sec
}, function (err, q) {
      ch.bindQueue(q.queue, "my_intermediate_exchange", '');
});

ch.assertQueue("my_final_delayed_queue", {}, function (err, q) {
      ch.bindQueue(q.queue, "my_final_delayed_exchange", '');

      ch.consume(q.queue, function (msg) {
          console.log("delayed - [x] %s", msg.content.toString());
      }, {noAck: true});
});
```

Answer (score 11):

As I don't have enough reputation to add comment, posting a new answer. This is just an addition to what has been already discussed at http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/04/rabbitmq-scheduled-message-delivery.html

Except instead of setting ttl on messages, you can set it at queue level. Also you can avoid creating a new exchange just for the sake of redirecting the messages to different Queue. Here is sample Java code:

Producer:

```java
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class DelayedProducer {
    private final static String QUEUE_NAME = "ParkingQueue";
    private final static String DESTINATION_QUEUE_NAME = "DestinationQueue";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ConnectionFactory();
        connectionFactory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = connectionFactory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        Map<String, Object> arguments = new HashMap<String, Object>();
        arguments.put("x-message-ttl", 10000);
        arguments.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "");
        arguments.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", DESTINATION_QUEUE_NAME );
        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, arguments);

        for (int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            String message = "This is a sample message " + i;
            channel.basicPublish("", QUEUE_NAME, null, message.getBytes());
            System.out.println("message "+i+" got published to the queue!");
            Thread.sleep(3000);
        }

        channel.close();
        connection.close();
    }
}
```

Consumer:

```java
import com.rabbitmq.client.ConnectionFactory;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Connection;
import com.rabbitmq.client.Channel;
import com.rabbitmq.client.QueueingConsumer;

public class Consumer {
   private final static String DESTINATION_QUEUE_NAME = "DestinationQueue";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
        factory.setHost("localhost");
        Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
        Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

        channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);
        System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

        QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
        boolean autoAck = false;
        channel.basicConsume(DESTINATION_QUEUE_NAME, autoAck, consumer);

        while (true) {
            QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
            String message = new String(delivery.getBody());
            System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
            channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You very much. I think you you have a small mistake in the consumer queue declare  channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null); It should have the "DESTINATION_QUEUE_NAME" instead of "QUEUE_NAME". Really thank you very very much

Answer (score 8):

It looks like [this blog post](http://blog.james-carr.org/2012/03/30/rabbitmq-sending-a-message-to-be-consumed-later/) describes using the dead letter exchange and message ttl to do something similar.

The code below uses CoffeeScript and Node.js to access Rabbit and implement something similar.

```coffeescript
amqp   = require 'amqp'
events = require 'events'
em     = new events.EventEmitter()
conn   = amqp.createConnection()
  
key = "send.later.#{new Date().getTime()}"
conn.on 'ready', ->
  conn.queue key, {
    arguments:{
      "x-dead-letter-exchange":"immediate"
    , "x-message-ttl": 5000
    , "x-expires": 6000
    }
  }, ->
    conn.publish key, {v:1}, {contentType:'application/json'}
  
  conn.exchange 'immediate'
 
  conn.queue 'right.now.queue', {
      autoDelete: false
    , durable: true
  }, (q) ->
    q.bind('immediate', 'right.now.queue')
    q.subscribe (msg, headers, deliveryInfo) ->
      console.log msg
      console.log headers
```

Comment: Link in answer is dead - *"PAGE NOT FOUND | 404"*.

Answer (score 6):

That's currently not possible. You have to store your expiration timestamps in a database or something similiar, and then have a helper program that reads those timestamps and queues a message.

Delayed messages are an often requested feature, as they're useful in many situations. However, if your need is to expire client sessions I believe that messaging is not the ideal solution for you, and that another approach might work better.

Answer (score 1):

> Suppose you had control over the consumer, you could achieve the delaying on the consumer like this??:
>
> If we are sure that the nth message in the queue always has a smaller delay than the n+1th message (this can true for many use cases): The producer sends timeInformation in the task conveying the time at which this job needs to be executed (currentTime + delay). The consumer:
>
> 1) Reads the scheduledTime from the task
>
> 2) if currentTime > scheduledTime go ahead.
>
> > Else delay = scheduledTime - currentTime
> >
> > > sleep for time indicated by delay
>
> The consumer is always configured with a concurrency parameter. So, the other messages will just wait in the queue until a consumer finishes the job. So, this solution could just work well though it looks awkward especially for big time delays.

Answer (score 0):

AMQP protocol does not support delayed messaging, but by using [Time-To-Live and Expiration](https://www.rabbitmq.com/ttl.html) and  [Dead Letter Exchanges](https://www.rabbitmq.com/dlx.html) extensions delayed messaging is possible. The solution is described in this [link](http://Step%20by%20step:%20%20%20%20%20%20Declare%20the%20delayed%20queue%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Add%20the%20x-dead-letter-exchange%20argument%20property,%20and%20set%20it%20to%20the%20default%20exchange%20%22%22.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Add%20the%20x-dead-letter-routing-key%20argument%20property,%20and%20set%20it%20to%20the%20name%20of%20the%20destination%20queue.%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20Add%20the%20x-message-ttl%20argument%20property,%20and%20set%20it%20to%20the%20number%20of%20milliseconds%20you%20want%20to%20delay%20the%20message.%20%20%20%20%20Subscribe%20to%20the%20destination%20queue). I copied the following steps from that link:

> Step by step:
>
> ```
> Declare the delayed queue
>     Add the x-dead-letter-exchange argument property, and set it to the default exchange "".
>     Add the x-dead-letter-routing-key argument property, and set it to the name of the destination queue.
>     Add the x-message-ttl argument property, and set it to the number of milliseconds you want to delay the message.
> Subscribe to the destination queue
> ```

There is also a plugin for delayed messaging in [RabbitMQ repository on GitHub](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange).

Note that there is a solution called [Celery](https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/userguide/calling.html) which supports delayed task queuing on RabbitMQ broker by presenting a calling API called `apply_async()`. Celery supports Python, node and PHP.