# how to run task at scheduled time with RabbitMQ

Tags: python, scheduled-tasks, rabbitmq, message-queue

I'm using [`RabbitMQ`](http://www.rabbitmq.com/)  to make my tasks pool run sequentially one by one. But how can add a time parameter to make a task only run at the **defined time in the future** (like a `scheduled tasks`).

Comment: This question should get more upvotes

Answer (score 8):

RabbitMQ is not a task scheduler, even though [the documentation](http://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-two-python.html) talks about "scheduling" a task. You might consider using something like cron. You could also use a library like [sched](http://docs.python.org/2/library/sched.html) to build a scheduler in a Python process.

FYI It looks like this question has already been answered:
[Delayed message in RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444208/delayed-message-in-rabbitmq)

Answer (score 5):

RabbitMQ has a plugin for [delayed messages](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-delayed-message-exchange).

Using this plugin, the messages can be delivered to the respective queues after a certain delay. Thanks to this plugin, you can use RabbitMQ as a scheduler, even though it's not a task scheduler by nature.

Answer (score 2):

You can use celery along with rabbitmq as broker for task scheduling. Here is the celery documentation http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/master/index.html