# How to implement delayed messaging in rabbitmq using spring-boot without using plugin

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq

I am trying to implement delayed messaging in rabbitmq using spring-boot without using a plugin.

I tried using the answers posted here - https://ivanyu.me/blog/2015/02/16/delayed-message-delivery-in-rabbitmq/

but no luck, can anyone throw some light on how to do it without using plugin ? I am able to do it using plugin.

Tried this in spring boot - https://ivanyu.me/blog/2015/02/16/delayed-message-delivery-in-rabbitmq/

Queue Bean config:

```
    Map<String, Object> args = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    args.put("x-dead-letter-exchange", "amq.direct");
    args.put("x-dead-letter-routing-key", "spring-boot-delayed-7");
    args.put("x-message-ttl", 5000);
    Queue messageQueueName = new Queue(queueName, false, false, false, args);
    return messageQueueName;
```

Message has to be delayed by 5 seconds.

Comment: Why the `Dead Letter Exchange` solution not works? Please give more detail.

Comment: The delayed queue `spring-boot-delayed-7` has been created and bounded correctly?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/43276108/1753177

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your reply. Yes, I did bound the queue correctly. I believe I am missing a logic here. Theory says I have push the message to QUEUE1 with TTL and once the TTL expires, message gets pushed to QUEUE2. But I am not able figure it out how to bind QUEUE2.

Comment: It is working in my local with this, but I used DirectExchange instead Fanout Exchange - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444208/delayed-message-in-rabbitmq/43276108#43276108