# Rabbitmq Delayed messaging is not working with spring cloud stream

Tags: spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-cloud-stream

I am trying to implement delayed message (without using rabbitmq plugin) in spring cloud stream but it's not working

I implemented it using spring-boot and it worked fine. Below is the sample code that I did in spring-boot.

[Delayed message in RabbitMQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4444208/delayed-message-in-rabbitmq/43276108#43276108)

I am trying to do the same in spring-cloud-stream but no help. Below are the properties.

Output channel - Producer

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=temp-channel
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.group=temp-channel-group
```

Input channel - Consumer

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=temp-channel
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group = temp-channel-group

spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.exchange-type=direct
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.bind-queue=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.binding-routing- 
key=foo.bar.key
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.required-groups=final- 
channel-group-1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-ttl=5000
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-dead-letter- 
exchange=final-channel-1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-dead-letter-queue=final- 
channel-group-1
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.consumer.dlq-dead-routing- 
key=foo.bar.key
```

When implemented with spring-boot, I see the message stays in the Temporary queue for the specified time and then moves to Final queue, I want to achieve the same with spring cloud stream. Any inputs would be appreciated.

Comment: So what happened with this prop, `final-channel-1` Exchange and `final-channel-group-1` Queue have been created and binded? Are `x-dead-letter-exchange` and `x-dead-letter-routing-key` and `x-message-ttl` be configured in Queue's arg?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be consuming from the temp-channel.

The whole point is you produce to a queue with a TTL, the TTL expires and routes the message to the DLQ; you then consume from the DLQ.

Consumers don't have `required-groups`, producers do.

This is what you need:

producer:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.destination=temp-exchange
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.output.producer.required-groups=delayed-group
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.auto-bind-dlq=true
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.ttl=5000
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.dead-letter-exchange=final-dest
spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.output.producer.dead-letter-queue-name=final-dest.delayed-group
```

consumer:

```
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.destination=final-dest
spring.cloud.stream.bindings.input.group=delayed-group
```

Which will create these queues:

```
temp-exchange.delayed-group

    x-dead-letter-exchange: final-dest
    x-dead-letter-routing-key:  temp-exchange.delayed-group
    x-message-ttl:  5000
    durable:    true

final-dest.delayed-group
```

Comment: Thanks Gary for detailed info. I did try your suggestion and it is not working as expected. It is only creating "Queue final-dest.anonymous.2m9ib1fIS82rTSAIcKLegg"

x-queue-master-locator: client-local
exclusive: true
auto-delete: true

Comment: That's an anonymous queue for a consumer with no group. You must add a consumer group to get the proper naming - see my answer. The temporary queue with TTL is created by the producer side; via the required groups property. Pay attention to the `letter-queue-name=final-dest.delayed-group`. That is the queue naming convention `<destination>.<group>`.

Comment: Hi Russell, I was trying Output, Input declarations and it didn't work. Today I came to know about latest api Source, Sink and tried, it worked. Thanks much.